# Is it still correct that OpenApi 3.x only can generate server-side code when using Jersey 2.x?

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0, openapi-generator

I've double checked here https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/#client-generators
But I just wanted someone to confirm that I am understanding this document correctly.

Is it true that OpenApi 3.x currently only supports the server-side generation of code for Jersey 2.x?
Is there any talk about an implementation for the client-side code generation for the near future?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java` client generator and specify `library` as `jersey2` to generate Java (Jersey2) API clients based on the API specifications/documents you provided.

Answer (score 0):

With OpenApi version 7.1 will be also a Jersey3 / OpenApi 3.x server-side generator available.
See: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/16676